# Why does my iphone simulator's apps keep crashing?

Tags: xcode, crash, ios-simulator

Whenever i run my applications on my simulator it crashes

This has never happened before..

any thoughts?

Comment: Can't help without more information. We need some crashing code, a crash log, or (at the bare minimum) a sense of what's different between your runs on the simulator and your testing device (if any). What SDK are you using? Target OS version (both Simulator and device)?

Comment: well this is a new application that i made
3.0?

Answer (score 0):

You should find crash reports of apps that crashed running in the simulator in your user home directory under `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/`